# Swi prolog Error: Showing true but not false

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog

Just installed SWI-Prolog on my W8 machine and it's throwing an error.

Here's the error:

```
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: mark/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

Let's say my prolog source file contains one fact:

```
 Prolog source...

 it_is_monday.   //The fact
```

So I compile the buffer, and get:

```
.../documents/prolog/prologSource compiled 0.00 sec, 2 clauses
```

Now when I input

```
it_is_monday.
```

The output as expected is `true`. However when I input say,

```
some_other_statement.
```

I get the error posted above as opposed to false. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Solution: Different prolog version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a standard Prolog flag, `unknown`, that is set by default in SWI-Prolog and other modern Prolog compilers to `error`, meaning that an attempt to call an unknown predicate will result in an exception. This flag can be set (using the standard `set_prolog_flag/2` predicate) instead to `fail` to get the behavior that you seem to be expecting but that's not advisable as it may make debugging harder. E.g. a simply typo in a predicate name will result in a failure which, in a complex program, could be difficult to trace down while a predicate existence error would pinpoint the culprit at the spot.

Comment: Yes, it's a helpful feature. My failure to define a predicate, or some typo/change to naming a predicate, is far and away my most typical error in writing Prolog.  Of course if one wants to stub out a predicate with a `fail` consequence, that can be a useful tactic.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error

`ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: mark/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)`

because you haven't defined the procedure you tried to execute. (that's why it says `undefined`)

If you define it, by editing your `.pl` file and writing
`some_other_statement.`

and you run it again, you'll get

```
1 ?- some_other_statement.
true.
```

In Prolog you need to define every procedure you want to execute.

When you try to execute an undefined procedure, the name of the procedure will show up in the error. So, if you haven't defined `some_other_statement.`, the error will be:

```
2 ?-  some_other_statement.
ERROR: toplevel: Undefined procedure: some_other_statement/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

notice that `some_other_statement/0` *is* being shown on the error that I got.

**EDIT :** If you wanted to get a `false` message, you would have to define something like `some_other_statement(1).` and then execute a query like `some_other_statement(12).`

```
2 ?- some_other_statement(12).
false.
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't state in the question that I was expecting false rather than the error, hence the confusion.
I was using an older version of prolog on my other machine which output false when an undefined procedure was presented.

Comment: I edited my post. I don't know about older versions, but on the current one, you get the mentioned error

Answer (score -1):

if you want to receive false from that you can add the directive

```
:- dynamic(some_other_statement/0).
```

at the beggining of the file, so when you execute the query

```
?- some_other_statement.
```

you will get false